# split a list of sentences to a list of words with python

Tags: python, string, split

I have a list of sentence

```
s: 'hello everyone', 'how are you',..., 'i am fine'.
```

I would like to split this list of sentences to a list of words.

So my expected result:

```
[['hello', 'everyone'], ['how', 'are', 'you'], .., ['i', 'am', 'fine]]
```

I try like this :

```
def split_list(sentence):
    for s in sentence:
        s=s.split()
    return s
```

but i got one list of words, not a list of list of words.

```
['hello', 'everyone', 'how', 'are', 'you', .., 'i', 'am', 'fine]
```

Comment: How does your list of sentences look, it's not very clear from the question Also could you should us how you are calling the function @cyrinepersonne

Comment: `list(map(str.split, s))`

Comment: Passing a list of sentences to your function does not return the result you posted

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear on what `sentence` refers to in your function `split_list`, but if it is a list of strings like `['hello everyone', 'how are you', 'i am fine']`, you end up overwriting the same string `s` on every iteration, and end up getting the result of the last iteration, i.e. `['i', 'am', 'fine']`

So you need to ensure that you are collecting all your results in a list of lists and returning that.

You can do that list-comprehension like so, assuming it is a list of strings like above

```
s = ['hello everyone', 'how are you', 'i am fine']

def split_list(sentence):
    # Split each sentence in the list, and append to result list
    return [item.split() for item in sentence]

print(split_list(s))
```

Or a normal for loop

```
s = ['hello everyone', 'how are you', 'i am fine']

def split_list(sentence):
    result = []
    #Split each sentence in the list, and append to result list
    for s in sentence:
        result.append(s.split())
    return result

print(split_list(s))
```

The output will be same for both cases.

```
[['hello', 'everyone'], ['how', 'are', 'you'], ['i', 'am', 'fine']]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can just be done with a list comprehension.

```
s = ['hello everyone', 'how are you', 'i am fine']
s2 = [c.split() for c in s]
print(s2) # [['hello', 'everyone'], ['how', 'are', 'you'], ['i', 'am', 'fine']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the result of each iteration in a list by initializing an empty list before the loop and appending each result in the loop:

```
def split_list(sentence):
    L = []
    for s in sentence:
        L.append(s.split())
    return L
```

Otherwise the function will return only the result of the last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
s = ['hello everyone', 'how are you', 'i am fine']

token = [word_tokenize(x) for x in s]
print(token)

o/p
[['hello', 'everyone'], ['how', 'are', 'you'], ['i', 'am', 'fine']]
```